# Вопрос по скобкам self-invoking JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Есть такой кусок кода:

```
(function aaa(){alert("555")})()
```

и такой:

```
(function aaa(){alert("555")}())
```

Оба они правильно выводят результат, т.е. синтаксических ошибок нет.

Вот только чем они отличаются, помимо написания скобок?

Comment: Ничем не отличаются

Answer (score 5):

функция внутри является не Function Declaration, а частью выражения, то есть
 Named Function Expression. Его имя видно только внутри, снаружи Его не видно.По этому выражние исполнится и потом викенит ошибку.Оно должно быть либо присвоено либо завершенной точкой с запятой  `;` .

```
(function aaa(){alert("555")}());
```

[Именованные функциональные выражения](https://learn.javascript.ru/named-function-expression)

А первый это само декларируемая функция,она как бы работает как Expression и сама себя присваивает и тут же вызывает.

[Тут тоже можно почитать](http://www.codehint.ru/articles/2014-07-27_javascript-self-invoking-functions)